# Is it possible to receive calls using CallKit in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, callkit

In iOS, one can show incoming call ui by using [CallKit's reportIncomingCall](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930694-reportnewincomingcall).

In my case, this works as expected in physical device. My iPhone gets incoming call alert and I can either accept the call or reject the call.

However, it seems to be not working in iOS simulator. More specifically, `reportNewIncomingCall` method call itself succeeds, but then it gets ended immediately (I do not even get to see any call alert). In addition, `func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction)` gets invoked from CXProviderDelegate, which means the call has been ended.

I could not find in apple official documentation whether or not it is possible to test CallKit - reportIncomingCall in iOS Simulator.

Strangely, outgoing call with `reportOutgoingCall` with `CXCallController` seems to work fine in simulator, as I can see green status bar show up at the top of the iPhone when `CXStartCallAction` gets fulfilled.

So the only thing that I could not make it to work is receiving call with CallKit in iOS simulator. Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CallKit doesn't work on iOS simulators altogether, neither receiving calls nor making calls.
Starting any `CXTransaction` containing `CXStartCallAction` or `CXAnswerCallAction` on a simulator will fail instantly with `NSError.Code` value of `CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnknown` (zero).
You will have to use a real device to test your CallKit app.

And yes, I couldn't find this mentioned in any Apple documentation. In [this article](https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/devb0244142d) that mentions the differences between simulators and real devices, CallKit is not mentioned.

Notice also that simulators don't have the calls UI (the dial pad and recent calls)